# How to handle transaction rollback in @PreUpdate

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

I want to validate entities before persisting/updating them. To do so I use the @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations and throw an exception to rollback the transaction. Then I catch the exception and inform the user that the entity was not valid. Everything works fine for the @PrePersist but the @PreUpdate flood the log with warning and stack-trace before I can catch the exception.

Test entity:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name = "default";

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist() { throw new RuntimeException("Test runtime exception in prePersist"); }
    @PreUpdate
    private void preUpdate() { throw new RuntimeException("Test runtime exception in preUpdate"); }

    public String getName() {  return name;  }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

Test session bean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestSession {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("TestSession");
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    public void testRollback() {
        try {
            TestEntity entity = new TestEntity();
            em.persist(entity);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            logger.severe("Runtime exception catched in session bean.");
            if (ctx.getRollbackOnly()) {
                logger.info("Context rollbacked.");
            } else {
                logger.info("Context is ok.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void testRollback2() {
        try {
            TestEntity entity = em.find(TestEntity.class, new Long(1));
            if (entity != null) { entity.setName("test"); }

            em.flush();

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            logger.severe("Runtime exception catched in session bean.");
            if (ctx.getRollbackOnly()) {
                logger.info("Context rollbacked.");
            } else {
                logger.info("Context is ok.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output when calling testRollback:

```
GRAVE: Runtime exception catched in session bean.
INFO: Context rollbacked.
```

Output when calling testRollback2:

```
ATTENTION: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test runtime exception in preUpdate
        at test.entity.TestEntity.preUpdate(TestEntity.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.invokeMethod(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:402)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityListener.invokeMethod(EntityListener.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityClassListener.invokeMethod(EntityClassListener.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityListener.preUpdateWithChanges(EntityListener.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:704)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:200)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:980)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(UpdateObjectQuery.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:829)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:728)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1501)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1483)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1443)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitChangedObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3784)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1407)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1553)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:780)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:418)
        at test.session.TestSession.testRollback2(TestSession.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at $Proxy154.testRollback2(Unknown Source)
        at test.session.__EJB31_Generated__TestSession__Intf____Bean__.testRollback2(Unknown Source)
        at test.servlet.TestServlet2.processRequest(TestServlet2.java:42)
        at test.servlet.TestServlet2.doGet(TestServlet2.java:64)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

ATTENTION: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test runtime exception in preUpdate
        at test.entity.TestEntity.preUpdate(TestEntity.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.invokeMethod(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:402)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityListener.invokeMethod(EntityListener.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityClassListener.invokeMethod(EntityClassListener.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityListener.preUpdateWithChanges(EntityListener.java:379)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:704)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:200)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.updateObjectForWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:980)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(UpdateObjectQuery.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:829)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:728)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1501)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1483)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1443)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitChangedObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:3784)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1407)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1553)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:780)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.flush(EntityManagerWrapper.java:418)
        at test.session.TestSession.testRollback2(TestSession.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at $Proxy154.testRollback2(Unknown Source)
        at test.session.__EJB31_Generated__TestSession__Intf____Bean__.testRollback2(Unknown Source)
        at test.servlet.TestServlet2.processRequest(TestServlet2.java:42)
        at test.servlet.TestServlet2.doGet(TestServlet2.java:64)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

GRAVE: Runtime exception catched in session bean.
INFO: Context rollbacked.
```

The log seems to be generated by eclipselink. How am I supposed to handle transaction rollback inside @PrePersist method to avoid all this logging?

Answer (score 0):

It is just logging that the error occurred.  It should not have any impact.

You can turn logging off, or disable exception logging.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging